# How to handle Userstatus returning wrong date format

Tags: excel, vba

TLDR: A function in my vba code returns date as m/d/yyyy format, while settings recognize it as dd/mm/yyyy. What do?

Long version: I'm building a function in Excel to remove all users in a shared workbook that have a login older than todays date. I found the beautiful `ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus` which returns all users, their status, and their login date/time in an array. The problem is that despite all my possible settings being in UK and standard date format being dd/mm/yyyy, the `.userstatus` returns it as m/d/yyyy. For example: 4th Oct gets returned as 10/4/2019. To make it worse, it's returned as a string instead of a "Double" date. So fixing this using `Format`, `CDate` or `CDbl` doesn't work. I would like to `dateadd` 1 day to this date and check it against the current date, but this is proving more challenging than expected.

Sample code:

```
Sub user()
Dim users As Variant, row As Integer
users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
    Debug.Print users(1, 2) 'Returns 10/4/2019 7:28, for 4th of Oct.
    Debug.Print DateAdd("d", 1, users(1, 2)) 'Returns 11/04/2019 07:28:00 which should be 5th of Oct.
End Sub
```

**Ps.** I realise I am asking this on 10/10, which is going to mess with your results when trying to replicate this issue. I sincerely apologise for this. It took me forever to find out this was the issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to UK date format and changed the date to 20th October to test it. I found that using `Format()` fixes the problem for me.

Here's what I'm getting:

```
Sub user()
    Dim users As Variant, row As Integer
    users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
    Debug.Print users(1, 2) 'Returns 10/20/2019 12:28, for 20th of Oct.
    Debug.Print Format(DateAdd("d", 1, users(1, 2)), "m/d/yyyy hh:mm") 'Returns 10/21/2019 12:28
End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This did not fix my problem, as your method still returned 11/20 for me. However this did put me in the right path, I forced the formatting of the return string as a date in its own format `Format(users(1,2), "m/d/yyyy hh:mm")` and then wrapped the dateadd around that. This returned the required result as a "Double" date as normal, which I could then format however I liked it.